# Where can I get testnet Bitcoins in the year 2017-March?

Tags: mining-reward, testnet

I doing some development and want to test out some stuff on testnet. Where can I get testnet coins in bitcoin? Last I read I might be able to mine with the Bitcoin core software? Or is that not worth it anymore? What are some places to get testnet coins in 2017-March?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet
Try to give them back when you are done with them. Also a simple google search "testnet faucet" would have found you that site and similar ones.